# Web SQL automatically defaults to SQLite in Android devices?

Tags: android, sqlite, jquery-mobile, web-sql

I ran a sample jQuery mobile app on my mobile IDE, that uses a local database for storing data. 
The code statements used are as below.  I am running it in a simulator and not on an actual device.

**My question is**: With these statements, am I using Web SQL or SQLite?

The reason for this confusion is when I debug this app in the mobile IDE, I find it says Web SQL as well as SQLite, which is confusing to me (look at the screen shot of the IDE at end of this post).

```
  var db = openDatabase("Test", "1.0", "Test", 65535);


        $("#create").bind("click", function (event) {
            db.transaction(function (transaction) {
                var sql = "CREATE TABLE customers " +

                          " (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +

                          "lname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, " + 

                          "fname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)"

                transaction.executeSql(sql, undefined, function () { 
                    alert("Table created");
                }, error);
            });
        });
```

[image: Web SQL or SQLite?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSQL is a specification that describes an interface between JavaScript code and a database.

SQLite is the database that you access through WebSQL.
(For compatibility reasons, all WebSQL implementations use SQLite.)

Comment: CL - So the code statements in my post, are essentially accessing a SQLite database?

Comment: CL - Thanks for the excellent answer. It makes everything very clear now.